# Django rest framework nested serializer not working for M2M relations

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class IP(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(unique=True)

class IPGroup(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ips = models.ManyToManyField(IP, through=IPGroupToIP)

class IPGroupToIP(models.Model):
    ip_group = models.ForeignKey(IPGroup)
    ip = models.ForeignKey(IP)
```

My **serializers.py** looks like this:

```
class IPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IP
        fields = ['id', 'host_name', 'ip_address']


class IPGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ips = IPSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = IPGroup
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Pop out ips since these are M2M relations and have to be created separately
        ips_data = validated_data.pop('ips', None)
        # Create the IPGroup object 
        ip_group_obj = IPGroup.objects.create(name=validated_data['name'])

        if ips_data:
            for ip in ips_data:
                # Get the ip object id if already created or create it on the fly and save it
                ip_obj, created = IP.objects.get_or_create(host_name=ip['host_name'], ip_address=ip['ip_address'])
                # Update through table for M2M relationship
                IPGroupToIP.objects.create(ip_group_id=ip_group_obj.id, ip_id=ip_obj.id)
        return ip_group_obj
```

and finally my **views.py** look like this:

```
class IPGroupCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = IPGroup.objects.get_queryset()
    serializer_class = IPGroupSerializer
```

This works as expected and sending the following JSON create request to the API endpoint does the job:

```
{
"name":"TestIPGroup1",
"ips": [{"name":"host1","value":"8.8.4.4"}, {"name":"host2","value":"8.8.8.8"}]
}
```

However, if I send another JSON create request with the same IPs for a new IPGroup as follows:

```
{
"name":"TestIPGroup2",
"ips": [{"name":"host1","value":"8.8.4.4"}, {"name":"host2","value":"8.8.8.8"}]
}
```

it gives me an error stating that **IP address already exists**. Now this is happening, because the nested IPSerializer's IP field **unique** validation check kicks in. How can i disable the default field unique check ? My DRF version is 3.8.2

**EDIT**

I have tried overriding the following method but it does not seem to work:

```
class IPGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ips = IPSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = IPGroup
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'

    def run_validators(self, value):
        for validator in self.validators:
            if isinstance(validator, validators.UniqueValidator):
                self.validators.remove(validator)
        super(IPGroupSerializer, self).run_validators(value)
```

Comment: What version of django, DRF are you using? Can you also add your *custom validate method* to the code above?

Comment: @Angela..I have slighted edited the question..Now there is no custom validation..also specified the DRF version

Answer (score 1):

specify the `id` field explicitly and add `empty` validators as,

```
class IPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[])

    class Meta:
        model = IP
        fields = ['id', 'host_name', 'ip_address']
```

**UPDATE**

```
class IPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IP
        fields = ['id', 'host_name', 'ip_address']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nested = kwargs.pop('nested', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if nested:
            self.fields.update(
                {"id": serializers.IntegerField(validators=[])}
            )


class IPGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ips = IPSerializer(many=True, nested=True)

    # Your code
```

Comment: I want to disable the validation for IP only when creating an IPGroup since it is a M2M field...your solution will remove validation whenever an IP is created leading to duplicate ids in the DB...

Comment: updated the answer, It could be stop by overriding `__init()__` method

Comment: This is quite nice..Is it possible to disable just the unique value check and not every type of validation for that field ?

Comment: You can explicty mention validators as `IntegerField(validators=[validator_1,validator_2])` .

Comment: @Jerin..see edit..i also tried overriding the run_validator method but it does not seem to work..Would you have any idea about this

Comment: put your `run_validators()` method inside the `IPSerializer` class, not `IPGroupSerializer` class